# Passthrough PS/2 keyboard to guest OS

Tags: ubuntu, kvm, qemu, libvirt

OS Windows run on VM (ubuntu, libvirt, qemu-kvm). And I have PS/2 keyboard on host hardware. Is there any way to pass it to guest OS without lost of performance (maybe emulate USB keyboard with keys mapping from PS/2 keyboard). I tried to use Spice server (from libvirt GUI "Virtual Machine Manager"), but it gives very annoying delay when pressing keys.

Answer (score 2):

First you must use `virsh edit <vm-name>` to modify the configuration XML, as you can't do this through the virt-manager GUI.

Check your top-level `<domain>` tag.  It should look something like this:

```
<domain type='kvm' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
```

If the type isn't kvm, you've boarded the wrong flight - start over with a new VM.  If the xmlns:qemu attribute isn't there, add it.

If you already have a `<qemu:commandline>` section, then add these two lines inside it:

```
<qemu:arg value='-object'/>
<qemu:arg value='input-linux,id=kbd,evdev=/dev/input/eventN,grab_all=on,repeat=on'/>
```

If you don't, then create it right under the `<domain>` tag with those two tags inside it.

You will also need to create the keyboard device in the guest using the following XML, which you should add to the `<devices>` section:

```
<serial type='dev'>
<source path='/dev/input/eventN'/>
<target port='0'/>
</serial>
```

The second qemu:arg and the source path defined here both have `eventN` defined.  You will need to replace N with the input device number for your keyboard.  Don't change the target port - just the source path.

My keyboard device is 2, but yours might be 0, or some other number.  To find out which one yours is, do `dmesg | grep input` and look for your keyboard device.  Mine says:

```
input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2
```

You still want to use the path of /dev/input/eventN - this just lets you know what the right number is to use for N.  If you're using X with evdev, which you probably are, you can also find this information in the X logfile.  One caveat: Your device number might change if you reconfigure your host hardware.

Your keyboard will no longer be recognized by the host while you are using it in a guest.  To control the host, you can:

- Exit the guest, or

  Attach another keyboard via USB, or

  Log in via ssh, or

  Use a serial console.

I got most of this information from this link:

https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/5hja2k/how_do_you_pass_through_a_ps2_keyboard/

Answer (score 1):

I tried the steps from the other answer on Debian Bullseye and would like to update some instructions. I suggest to use `journalctl -b` and then search for `input.*keyboard`. My system had a longer uptime and dmesg did not show those lines anymore. I found:

```
kernel: input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/in>
systemd-logind[2716]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (AT Translated Set 2 keyboard)
```

With this I knew my keyboard was using event0 at the moment an thus I could find it via `ls -l /dev/input/by-path` as `/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd`.

Since libvirt version 7.4.0, the domain XML supports `<input type='evdev'>`. I updated libvirt from bullseye-backports to get version 8. So, all I had to add to my VM XML was:

```
<input type="evdev">
  <source dev="/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd" grab="all" grabToggle="ctrl-ctrl" repeat="on"/>
</input>
```

Note the additional `grabToggle="ctrl-ctrl"` which allows to switch keyboard between guest and host by left ctrl + right ctrl.

I got this from [Archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#Passing_keyboard/mouse_via_Evdev). This also contains suggestions for further delay reduction by "switching from PS/2 to Virtio inputs", but I have not tried this.

The benefit of this approach is that you do not have to configure additional ACL/permissions for Qemu to use your keyboard. This caused problems on my side when I tried the approach with the `qemu:commandline` section.