# Passthough special keys from keyboard to guest OS?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, libvirt, keyboard-event

I have a MS Natural Keyboard 4000 and I want to use its special keys in my guest OS. Both are Linux Mint.

Without any additional configuration some keys are passed (<kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Mail</kbd>, <kbd>Volume</kbd>, <kbd>Fav</kbd>, etc.) but <kbd>Search</kbd> and <kbd>Launch5</kbd>...<kbd>Launch9</kbd> are not.

I tried two passthrough configs using 'virtsh':

- `/dev/input/event19`
- `/dev/input/by-id/usb-Microsoft_Natural®_Ergonomic_Keyboard_4000-if01-event-kbd`

But both did not change anything, although both inputs are working as expected on on my host OS using `cat`.

What's wrong in my setup? Or how can I pass the 6 missing keys else?

```xml
  ...
  <serial type='dev'>
    <source path='/dev/input/by-id/usb-Microsoft_Natural®_Ergonomic_Keyboard_4000-if01-event-kbd'/>
    <target type='isa-serial' port='0'>
      <model name='isa-serial'/>
    </target>
  </serial>
</devices>

...
<qemu:commandline>
    <qemu:arg value='-object'/>
    <qemu:arg value='input-linux,id=kbd,evdev=/dev/input/by-id/usb-Microsoft_Natural®_Ergonomic_Keyboard_4000-if01-event-kbd,grab_all=on,repeat=on'/>
</qemu:commandline>
```

[Reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198736/passthrough-ps-2-keyboard-to-guest-os)